# Rails 3 / nested routes: Problem to redirect to the correct url for a collection of microposts in a user show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, nested-routes

I have a problem with nested routes which don't display correct url.

I use the below code, but it renders something like:

```
.../users/[:user_id]/microposts/[:user_id]
```

instead of:

```
.../users/[:user_id]/microposts/[:micropost_id]
```

for every microposts displayed in the user show pages.

## Associations

```
has_many :microposts #user model
belongs_to :users #micropost model
```

## routes

```
resources :microposts, :only => [:create, :destroy]
resources :users, :only => [:show] do
  resources :microposts, :only => [:show]  
end
```

## Microposts_controller

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @micropost = @user.microposts.find(params[:id])
end
```

## microposts/_micropost.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "show this micropost" user_micropost_url(@user) %> #link for every microposts displayed in the user show pages
```

## user/show.html.erb

```
<%= render @microposts %>
```

I can't see where I am wrong.
Thank a lot for your help!

## EDIT

```
if I use [@user, @micropost ] the displayed url is .../users/[:user_id]
if I use user_micropost_url(@user, @micropost) it renders an error:

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"microposts", :user_id=>#<User id: 1
```

Routes:

```
user_micropost GET /users/:user_id/microposts/:id(.:format) {:action=>"show", :controller=>"microposts"}
microposts POST   /microposts(.:format) {:action=>"create", :controller=>"microposts"}
micropost DELETE /microposts/:id(.:format) {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"microposts"}
user GET    /users/:id(.:format) {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass in @micropost as well:

```
<%= link_to "show this micropost", user_micropost_url(@user, @micropost) %> #link for every microposts displayed
```

You could also shorten it to:

```
<%= link_to "show this micropost", [@user, @micropost] %> #link for every microposts displayed
```

Comment: Hi Ant, thanks for your answer, I tried this but it renders the following error: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"microposts", :user_id=>#<User id: 1, ...

Comment: Hmmm, run rake routes in your console and paste what's there into your question please. Also the microsposts controller would be useful.

Comment: Thanks Ant! the microposts controller is already displayed and I add routes and error or url behavior.

Comment: You seem to be missing the microposts routes, have you tried restarting the server?

Comment: Yes (sorry I edit a bit I paste something wrong) I have microposts routes for the following action => :show, :create and :destroy and i restarted the server with no luck for url :(

Comment: Everything seems to be ok and user_micropost_url(@user, @micropost) should work. Do the other actions in your microposts controller work ok?

Comment: Yep it is really strange.. I'll do it thanks for your backup!!

Comment: Just to close this, it was user_micropost_url(:user, @micropost)